# UILabel unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I have a custom UITableViewCell with 3 UILabels. Each of them the text is set `label.text = @"something";`. But when I scroll past (lets say cell 0) and then scroll back up to it, the app crashes with `-[__NSCFString setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` with the line where I set the text highlighted red. Also all the other cells (that use the same re-usable cell) do not have that label populated. In the UITableViewCell subclass I have the properties set with `strong`.

Class with UITableView:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
ChampionDetailSpellCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"championAbilityCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
// Performance
cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;

// Design
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundView = nil;

// Reset
cell.abilityIcon.image = nil;
cell.abilityNameLabel.text = nil;
cell.abilityCost.text = nil;
cell.abilityRange.text = nil;
cell.abilityDescription.text = nil;

// Content
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    // Passive

    // Icon
    [DDragon getChampionPassiveIcon:self.championInfo[@"passive"][@"image"][@"full"] :^(NSURL *championPassiveIconURL) {
        [cell.abilityIcon setImageWithURL:championPassiveIconURL];
    }];

    // Name
    cell.abilityNameLabel.text = self.championInfo[@"passive"][@"name"];

    // Tooltip
    cell.abilityDescription.text = self.championInfo[@"passive"][@"sanitizedDescription"];
} else {
    // Ability

    // Image
    [DDragon getChampionAbilityIcon:self.championInfo[@"spells"][indexPath.row - 1][@"image"][@"full"] :^(NSURL *championAbilityIconURL) {
        [cell.abilityIcon setImageWithURL:championAbilityIconURL];
    }];

    // Name
    cell.abilityNameLabel = self.championInfo[@"spells"][indexPath.row - 1][@"name"];

    // Cost
    cell.abilityCost.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.championInfo[@"spells"][indexPath.row - 1][@"costBurn"], self.championInfo[@"spells"][indexPath.row - 1][@"costType"]];

    // Range
    cell.abilityRange.text = self.championInfo[@"spells"][indexPath.row - 1][@"rangeBurn"];

    // Tooltip
    cell.abilityDescription.text = self.championInfo[@"spells"][indexPath.row - 1][@"sanitizedTooltip"];
}

return cell;
}
```

UITableViewCell subclass

```
@interface ChampionDetailSpellCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *abilityIcon;
@property (strong) IBOutlet UILabel *abilityNameLabel;
@property (strong) IBOutlet UILabel *abilityCost;
@property (strong) IBOutlet UILabel *abilityRange;

@property (strong) IBOutlet UITextView *abilityDescription;

@end
```

Comment: Profile for Zombie objects and let us know the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this wrong :

// Name

```
cell.abilityNameLabel = self.championInfo[@"spells"][indexPath.row - 1][@"name"];
```

I think it should be :

```
// Name
cell.abilityNameLabel.text = self.championInfo[@"spells"][indexPath.row - 1][@"name"];
```

Comment: Darn it. Its one of those moments where you read something to see if you made a stupid mistake but your brain fills in the error making it look right to you until someone else points it out.